# Find string in array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, foreach

I have two different arrays and I am trying to filter the one while looping the other.

```
const serviceCodes = 
[
  {
    ...otherStuff...
    "codes": [
      "786410010",
      "787885010"
    ]
  }
]
```

and

```
const laborCost = 
[
  {
    "laborCode": "786410010",
    "estimatedCost": {
      "value": -1,
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  },
  {
    "laborCode": "787885010",
    "estimatedCost": {
      "value": -1,
      "currency": "USD"
    }
  }
]
```

I am looping through `serviceCodes` and trying to return only the object that matches the laborCode

```
const serviceMatchesRow = serviceCodes[0].codes.forEach((code) => {
  return laborCost?.find(
    (service) => service.laborCode === code,
  )
})
```

This is returning undefined as `forEach` only runs through it, but if I use `.map` instead, then it return the 2 objects within `laborCost`. If I change for `.find` instead, than it returns an array with the `laborCode` itself `["786410010", 787885010]`.

So how can I get around this?

The desired output would be something like:

```
[{
  "laborCode": "786410010",
  "estimatedCost": {
    "value": -1,
    "currency": "USD"
  }
}]
```

Comment: Can you share your desired output? According to the above example?

Comment: Note: `forEach` doesn't return anything. It just processes the elements.

Comment: @vbotio try this https://jsfiddle.net/SeeratAhmed/pchjyztr/4/

Answer (score 0):

forEach method doesn’t return anything

so you should insert the matches objects in new array.
or use .map method

```
const serviceMatchesRow = [];
 serviceCodes[0].codes.map((code) => {
    serviceMatchesRow.push(laborCost.find((service) => { 
        return service.laborCode === code 
        }
    ));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem: You're trying to return from within the foreach block; that will not return anything thats why you see undefined.

Solution: Use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) to return while iterating on an array.

```
const serviceMatchesRow = serviceCodes[0].codes.map((code) => {
  return laborCost.find(
    (service) => service.laborCode === code,
  )
})
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/240z5u3f/3/

Comment: I would prefer if your working example were a stack snippet in your answer rather than an external fiddle.  You don't need any jsfiddle features a stack snippet doesn't provide.